# Can I create a new web page from the HTML in a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that allows a user to choose some options for a widget and then dynamically generates example HTML based on those options. The HTML is put in a div on the page so that the user can see how it looks and copy/paste it to their own site, if they so desire.

I would like to add a "view this example page" link, which opens in a new window and has the example HTML from the div, so that the example can instantly be seen in action.

Is there a way to do this with javascript/jquery?

Comment: if it is full html (including header and html tag) you probably need to use an iframe, otherwise jQuery would be enough

Comment: Yes it's possible. Do you have any code to show what you've tried already?

Comment: It is full HTML. An iframe I can see how it would work, but I want it in a new window ideally. I don't have any code because I don't even know where to start when it's in a new window (I can do it in the existing window with document.write easily enough but that doesn't help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use the window.open method, saving a reference to the opened window, and then writing to it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

```
var exampleWin = window.open("", "example");
var docMarkup = "<!doctype html><html><head><title>test</title></head>" + 
"<body><p>Hello, world.</p></body></html>";
exampleWin.document.write(docMarkup);
// later you can also do exampleWin.close() if you wish
```

Try pasting the above code in your browser's developer tools console.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! Thanks :)

Comment: Interestingly I notice that the browser loading symbol keeps spinning on the new window until I hit stop. If I refresh it stops itself. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I have now uploaded the code to production, so you can see the never ending loading in action at https://www.palfed.com/make-wizard if it helps - just scroll down to the bottom and click on "view" next to "Example HTML that will work with the selected options"

Comment: I found out how to do it using exampleWin.document.close();

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to accomplish the end goal works a bit differently. You have a web server listening for `GET` requests at `/code` (or similar) and it constructs and responds with the appropriate HTML based on the query string. So you can request `/code?color=blue`, for example.

Constructing documents is what web servers are designed to do. This approach allows you to leverage caching policies, integrate with a wider variety of user authentication and authorization systems, etc.

To display the source code to the user, simply [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) the appropriate URL and put the contents in a [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) tag. To display the rendered widget, use an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) whose `src` is the same URL.

If you really want it to be a new window, [open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) the URL instead of using an iframe. But beware of popup blockers.